# How to put `throws IOException` to the statement

Tags: java, io, ioexception

I am trying to implement a `class` from  `HighestScoreFile.java` and when I compile, I get this error :

```
...MemoryGame.java:211: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                    HighestScoreFile.HighestScoreFile(input, hours, minutes, seconds, click);
                                                     ^
1 error
```

Before I implement this `HighestScoreFile.java`, I have tested with a `main` class using

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        HighestScoreFile("abcdefg", 12, 13, 14, 30);
    }
```

The `HighestScoreFile.java` is used to save the data into a `Highest.txt`.

But when I implement to another `.java` using the code below, it shows out that error.

```
HighestScoreFile.HighestScoreFile(input, hours, minutes, seconds, click);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either throw the exception outside of the method:

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException
{
    // ...
    HighestScoreFile.HighestScoreFile(input, hours, minutes, seconds, click);
    // ..
}
```

Or catch the excetion:

```
try 
{
    HighestScoreFile.HighestScoreFile(input, hours, minutes, seconds, click);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // handle the exception
}
```

I suggest you follow the [Java exception trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: Thanks. I forget about `try..catch` method. I'm using it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `throws IOException` to the declaration of `HighestScoreFile`

Answer (score 0):

you code try to throw another error rather than IOException, and you did not catch it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: the called method may throw an `IOException`, which *must be caught or declared to be thrown*.

So either you wrap the call in a `try-catch` block, or you declare that the caller method `throws IOException` too.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the `try..catch` method, and it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either declare the exception as thrown in your method (throws IOException in the method in your new java file) or surround it with a try / catch block

Comment: The method in the file `HighestScoreFile.java`, I had put `throws IOException`, but it's need `throws IOException` in the implemented file too.